Google calendar create event with Meet link attached with Service account
I am trying to integrate Google calendar with Node JS and create events, which is working all fine, but then once I try to add conferenceData it gives me 400, I am not sure what is wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated.
{
    summary: 'Coding class',
    location: 'Virtual / Google Meet',
    description: 'Learn how to code with Javascript',
    start: {
      dateTime: new Date().toISOString(),
      timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta',
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + 1)).toISOString(),
      timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta',
    },
    reminders: {
      useDefault: false,
      overrides: [
        { method: 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60 },
        { method: 'popup', 'minutes': 10 },
      ],
    },
    conferenceData: {
      createRequest: {
        conferenceSolutionKey: {
          type: 'hangoutsMeet',
        },
        requestId: new Date().getTime()
      }
    },
  };

const response = await calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      resource: event,
      conferenceDataVersion: 1
    });

I have tried hangoutsMeet & googleMeet but no luck.

Try setting your conferenceData field to something like this: "conferenceData": { "createRequest": { "requestId": 'myRandomString', "conferenceSolutionKey": { "type": 'hangoutsMeet' }. The Add video and phone conferences to events documentation states that You can create a new conference for an event by providing a createRequest with a newly generated requestId which can be a random string.

I did try that, but then it does not create the event and straight away gives 400

Understood.  Have you also tried the answer in this Stack Overflow post's answer? It talks about how one can update a created event to add a Google Meet link.

Yes, I did try it, but facing the same issue, that hangoutsMeet is not a valid conferenceSolutionKey
